# Updating names in a column with slight differences

Tags: sql, duplicates, sql-update, names

I have a column where there are slight differences in each name but I want to only use one of the names. I have using an update query but is there an easier way instead of doing an update query one by one? Examples below. There are multiple versions of the name and I only want to pick the first one.

Name

- NORTH HOSP
- NORTH HOSPITAL
- NORTHERN W HOSP
- NORTHERN WEST HOSPITAL
- NORTHERN W HOSPITAL
- BROTHERS MED CTR
- BROTHERS MEDICAL CENTER
- HEALTHALLY HOSP
- HEALTH ALLY HOSPITAL

Current code example:

```
update #tablename
set name='NORTH HOSP'
where name in ('NORTH HOSPITAL')

update #tablename
set name='HEALTHALLY HOSP'
where name in ('HEALTH ALLY HOSPITAL')
```

Comment: So are you trying to bring standardize all the names that are similar?

Comment: @MintBerryCRUNCH yes

Comment: well you can always add extra things to the `IN ('NORTHERN WEST HOSPITAL','NORTHERN W HOSPITAL')` but on the example you provide there is only one that would be worth doing that for.  If you really want it to be one statement you could do some sort of `IF THEN` statement. See attached link. What is the criteria for what gets standardized? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18682515/if-condition-in-sql-server-update-query